# PerformanceWarning for Pandas dataframe decoding URL string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a URL encoded column "event_properties_searchterm".

I use the following code to clean up, it works exactly as I expected but I got this warning:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()

```
    from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

    def clean_search_term(self, text: str) -> str:
        """Decode URL encodings back to Unicode string"""
        if not text:  # empty string or None
            return "empty_search_term"
        return unquote_plus(text).lower().strip()

    df["search_term"] = df["event_properties_searchterm"].apply(clean_search_term)
```

I tried just applying unquote_plus (although it doesn't do all I would like to do in the function above) as follows but still got the warning.

```
df["event_properties_searchterm"].apply(clean_search_term)
```

What can I do to improve it?
Python: 3.9.2
Pandas: 1.5.0

Comment: You might not be doing anything wrong this would suggest: https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/issues/340#issuecomment-879450854

Comment: Hi, what happens if you replace `df["search_term"] = df["event_properties_searchterm"].apply(clean_search_term)` with `df = pd.concat([df, df["event_properties_searchterm"].apply(clean_search_term).rename({"event_properties_searchterm": "search_term"})], axis=1)`?